# MYSQL Query, forming dropdown with specific results

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a MYSQL table, with the following information.  It is holding the date and time of a event someone  can register for.

### id date time registered

1 1362981600 9-noon 0
2 1363586400 9-noon 0
3 1364191200 9-noon 0
4 1362981600 1-4 pm 0
5 1363586400 1-4 pm 0
6 1364191200 1-4 pm 0
7 1363240800 1-4pm 0
8 1363845600 1-4pm 0
9 1363327200 9-noon 0
10 1363327200 1-4 pm 0
11 1363327200 3-7 pm 1

I need a mysql query that pulls all fields that are registered=0 and only shows one of each day (day as in Monday or Tuesday, etc) that has a time slot.

So if I did a select * from table where registered=0 I would get these results, using the timestamp to get the day of the week I generate the following using PHP while loop through the query.

Mondays, 9-noon
Mondays, 9-noon
Mondays, 9-noon
Mondays, 1-4 pm
Mondays, 1-4 pm
Mondays, 1-4 pm
Thursdays, 1-4 pm
Thursdays, 1-4 pm
Fridays, 9-noon
Fridays, 1-4 pm

What I would like to get is:
Mondays, 9-noon
Mondays, 1-4 pm
Thursdays, 1-4 pm
Fridays, 9-noon
Fridays, 1-4 pm

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a "group by" clause and you'll be all set. I don't know what formula you use to derive the day, so I use one arbitrarily below for illustration:

```
select date(from_unixtime(date)) as date
    , dayname(from_unixtime(date)) as day
    , time
    , min(date) as cronos
from table
where registered=0
group by date, day, time
order by cronos asc, time asc
```

different query to match added description in comments below:

```
select dayofweek(from_unixtime(date)) as day_num
    , dayname(from_unixtime(date)) as day_name
    , time
from table
where registered=0
group by day_num, day_name, time
order by day_num asc, time asc;
```

Comment: Ok just tried that, worked well thank you! but it resulted not sorted right.  it was listing friday 9-noon, friday 1-4pm, monday 1-4pm, monday 9-noon, thursday 1-4pm.  how can i list it out as I wrote it up there?  If its not possible to sort just like that, can i at least result out in order of days of the week so mondays are first and so on? Thanks!

Comment: If you want a guaranteed sort, then you need to add a "sort by" clause explicitly. Which means your select needs to have a field you can sort on. I've added the "min(date)" in my answer as an example. But it is not enough actually (because for the same date, you will also want to make sure the time slots are in order. If the time slots have been added chronologically to the table (meaning the id are increasing chronologically), you could use "min(id) as min_id", and "sort by min_id asc" .

Comment: Additionnaly, while I don't know your problem domain, it seems querying day of the week day alone is not enough because it means Monday next week for a given time slot will get bundled with Monday 2 weeks from now on the same time slot, which I assume is not what you want. So instead, you'll need to query both date and day for a given timestamp and group on that. Sorting based on time slot will be tricky because you'll need to parse the time column, you should try to change your db schema to make have a sortable time_slot definition (perhaps give time slots incremented ids).

Comment: Edited answer again. The sort on time is lame (because it's a string comparison). Again, you likely need to change your table schema structure to generate sortable time slots. A separate table with typical slots ordered chronologically by id would do.

Comment: First, Timothee thank you so much for taking the time out here with me tonight.  It is helping tremendously! 

Ok. I will explain the project a bit more. 

There is 1 drop box that has class types that the user selects. They are not attached to any specific date as any class type can be registered on any of the dates.

The idea is a user picks a class, then to simplify and not give them 1 huge drop down with 70+ classes, to first ask them their preferred day and time slot. This is where I was trying to build a query to get unique days and slots and show 1 of each but not more.

Comment: So if a user were to pick Mondays, 9-noon another dropbox below will populate and fill (using php) and i will do a ajax query to select * from table where time = '9-noon' and date = monday, then all the dates in option a below will appear in a drop down box.

a.       Mondays, 9-noon (3/11,3/18, 3/25, 4/8,4/15, 4/22,4/29, 5/6, 5/13, 5/20, 6/3)
b.      Mondays, 1-4pm (3/11, 3/18,3/25, 4/8,4/15, 4/22, 4/29, 5/6,5/13, 5/20, 6/3)

Comment: c.       Thursdays, 1-4pm (3/14,3/21, 3/28, 4/11, 4/18, 4/25, 5/2, 5/16, 5/23, 5/30)
d.      Fridays, 9-noon (3/15, 3/22,3/29, 4/12, 4/19, 4/26, 5/3,5/10, 5/17, 5/24, 5/31)
e.      Fridays, 1-4pm (3/15, 3/22,3/29, 4/12, 4/19, 4/26, 5/3,5/10, 5/17, 5/24, 5/31)
f.        Saturdays, 9-noon (3/16,3/23, 3/30, 4/13, 4/20, 4/27, 5/4, 5/11, 5/18, 5/25, 6/1)
g.       Saturdays, 1-4pm (3/16,3/23, 3/30, 4/13, 4/20, 4/27, 5/4, 5/11, 5/18, 5/25, 6/1)

Comment: Also, your last update is giving me a mysql error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sort by cronos asc, time asc' at line 8

Comment: Urgh, sorry about the syntax error, sql uses "order by" of course, not "sort by" (duh). Corrected that in my answer. As for the way you are approaching your problem, in that case, instead of sorting by min date, you should get the dayofweek and sort by that. will edit my answer again in a mn.

Comment: Added another query to match the day bundling as per your reqs. The ordering by time is still not right, you still need to have a sortable time column to solve this properly. I also assume you have the second part of the problem solved (retrieving the actual dates/slots for a given day in step 2 of your flow).